# PyTorch: Adding hooks to model for saving the intermediate layers output returns the features two times

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to implement the Style Transfer paper using Pytorch and the VGG19 network.
For this, I need the intermediate output features for some layers.
I named the convolutional modules: ['conv_1', 'conv_2',..., 'conv_16']

For managing the hooks and features I use this method:

```
class SaveOutput:
  #Callable object for saving the layers outputs
  def __init__(self):
    self.outputs = []
      
  def __call__(self, module, module_in, module_out):
    self.outputs.append(module_out)
      
  def clear(self):
    self.outputs = []

def addHooksToModel(model, layerNames, hookHandles):
  #Remove hooks
  for hook in hookHandles:
    hook.remove()

  hookHandles = []
  features = SaveOutput()

  for name, module in model.named_modules():
    if name in layerNames:
      hookHandles.append(module.register_forward_hook(features))

  return features, hookHandles
```

I want to store the features of the content and style separately:

```
CONTENT_LAYERS = ["conv_14"]
STYLE_LAYERS = ["conv_1","conv_3","conv_5","conv_9","conv_13"]

hook_handles_content = []
hook_handles_style = []
content_features, hook_handles_content = addHooksToModel(model, CONTENT_LAYERS, hook_handles_content)
style_features, hook_handles_style = addHooksToModel(model, STYLE_LAYERS, hook_handles_style)
```

I then pass the `contentImage` and `styleImage` through the network and I expect the `content_features.outputs` to contain 1 tensor and the `style_features.outputs` to contain 5 tensors.

```
model(contentImage)
contentImg_content = content_features.outputs
content_features.clear()

model(styleImage)
styleImg_style = style_features.outputs
style_features.clear()
```

But in reality, I get 1 tensor for the `content_features.outputs`(as expected), but 10 tensors for the `style_features.outputs`(two times the expected).
Same thing happens if I first pass the `styleImage` and then the `contentImage`. I get 5 tensors for the style_features.outputs(as expected), but 2 tensors for the content_features.outputs(two times the expected).

Could somebody point me in the right direction. I know I'm missing something, probably in the way Pytorch hooks are working, but I can't figure out what. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using `torchvision.models.vgg19`? Can you show how you renamed your layer?

Comment: Yes, but that was not the problem! I just didn't think it through. I posted the solution below. Sorry for taking your time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am the luckiest(for figuring out what's wrong) or the most distracted(for making the mistake in the first place) person.
When passing the `contentImage` through the network, the features get saved in both the `content_features`(1 tensor) and `style_features`(5 tensors) objects. Then, when passing the the `styleImage` through the network, I get an additional 5 tensors.
The solution was to clear both objects after passing the `contentImage`:

```
model(contentImage)
...
content_features.clear()
style_features.clear()

model(styleImage)
```